# How does multiple separators influence my program when using strtok?

Tags: c, file, strtok, separator

I have the following content in a text file:

```
5,Albert Einstein, 101
1,Nikola Tesla, 102
```

In the example I followed, the variables were read like:

```
char* token, separators[] = ",\n", name[30];
    int group;
    int prioKey;

    while (fgets(buffer, SIZE_BUFFER, pFile))
    {
        token = strtok(buffer, separators);
        prioKey = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, separators);
        strcpy(name, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, separators);
        group = atoi(token);

    }
```

My precise question would be: why in the separators[] I have both "," and "\n", don't I need only ","? How does that work? I see that after the name I have a " " which counts as "\n", but how does the program know what to use?

Comment: You don't need `'\n'`. `fgets` reads line by line.

Comment: `fgets` puts the newline (`'\n'`) at the end of the buffer. You _could_ strip it with (e.g.) `buffer[strcspn(buffer,"\n")] = 0;` after the `fgets` but before any `strtok` but that involves an extra scan. Easier to just put `'\n'` in your `separators`. Also, because you have `5,Albert Einstein, 101` and _not_ just `5,Albert Einstein,101` you should use: `separators[] = ", \n"` [now a space is also a delimiter]